# Get Screen Width in dpi Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to get a screen size in dpi. I've seen a way to use the **XLabs** library, can I do without it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Forms I think that you can do only this:

```
App.AppContext.ScreenSize.Width
App.AppContext.ScreenSize.Height
```

But you can obviously create a custom renderer, and in **Android** you have also these properties:

```
Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Xdpi
Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Ydpi
```

While in **iOS** these:

```
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height
```

For **UWP** [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation):

```
var display = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
double xDpi = display.RawDpiX;
double yDpi = display.RawDpiY;
```